# multithreaded server asynchronous java

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, sockets

Basically I need to make a server that handles multiple devices sending/receiving information. I have to be able to send commands to the devices. The number of devices is about 40 for now but will increase to maybe 400 over time. The devises will always send information once every 40seconds-60seconds which is set on the device so it can vary, but may also send more information depending on other factors, such as a responses to commands sent to it. So I have read there is java NIO which I can use or what I have currently done is created a thread for each incoming connection. The sending is not a constant thing so it needs to happen on demand, based on users input on my jsp website. So this is where I am stuck. How do I accomplish the sending of commands from outside the program where the connection is.

This is what I currently have:

Main server class to handle connections and make threads.

```
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)) { 
    while (listening) {
      ServerThread r = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept());
      Thread thread = new Thread(r);
      thread.setDaemon(true);
      System.out.println(thread.getId() + "thread");
      thread.start();
      thread.join();
         }
     } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port " + portNumber);
        System.exit(-1);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Then the ServerThread class:

```
    public class ServerThread implements Runnable{

private Socket socket = null;
public AtomicBoolean isStopped=new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
       this.socket = socket;
    }
    public void run() {
       while(!this.isStopped.get()){
        try (
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ) {

         ReceiveThread r = new ReceiveThread(in);
         Thread thread = new Thread(r);
         thread.setDaemon(true);
         thread.start();
         thread.join();
         socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    }

    }
```

Then the ReceiveThread handles the reading/decoding.

Comment: Try using Finagle which might be much simpler.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you don't try and solve this yourself but use one of the libraries specifically designed for solving this kind of problem. I'd choose one of either netty: http://netty.io/ or mina: http://mina.apache.org/

Comment: Can't you just use a servlet and return plain-text to the devices. Any restrictions? Its will be easy. Can your device open Http urls?

Comment: Multithreaded and asynchronous oare not the same thing. Get rid of the `join()`. It is completely unmotivated here. And also get rid of the socket close inside the loop. You simply have too much code for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

On demand infrequent communication is better handled via UDP maybe with re-transmission implementation if you need to make sure that data is received, alternatively you can use NIO channels to handle that.
Creating a `Thread` for every client if the communication is infrequent is wasteful and pointless.